# Inverse of the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, matrix, linear-algebra

Is the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution always invertible?

Comment: No, consider for instance $(X_1,X_2=2X_1)$ when $X_1\sim\mathcal N(0,1).$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the variables are perfectly correlated, i.e. $\rho=1$, then covariance matrix becomes:
$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ \sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

and its determinant is $\Delta=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2-\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2=0$, which means the matrix is not invertible. A possible case this occurs is $X_1=\alpha X_2$ as in @Xian's comment. Here $\alpha>0$, but for $\alpha<0$ $\rho=-1$ which still doesn't save the $\Sigma$.

It is only invertible when $|\rho|<1$ since the covariance matrix is actually 
$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
And, the determinant is $\Delta=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2)$, which is $>0$ when $|\rho|<1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Therefore, if I assume that all the variables are not correlated with one another, is my covariance matrix invertible?

Comment: Not correlated means $\rho=0$, and it is perfectly invertible. And, if some correlation exists such that $|\rho|<1$, still it is invertible since $\Delta>0$.

Comment: This comment thread seems to contain at least one pitfall for the unwary reader who might suppose it refers to anything more general than a *bivariate* normal distribution.  For multivariate normal distributions with *more* than two variables, it is possible for all correlation coefficients to be close to zero, yet the matrix can still be singular.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The covariance matrix of two perfectly correlated standard normal random variables is given by $\Sigma = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\1 & 1}$, which is not invertible.